# What punctuation mark should I use here?

Tags: punctuation

> Eventually we're hoping to compile a
>   list of schools[?] ones that would
>   benefit considerably from ...

Where `[?]` is, would a semi-colon suit? What punctuation mark would be correct here and why?

A simple comma perhaps?

Comment: More context is needed for a definitive answer. Is this the first part of an enumeration? Is there a special reason for using "ones"? How does the sentence continue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None.

Toss out *ones*:

> ... schools that would benefit...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using "such - which" as in *Eventually we're hoping to compile a list of **such** schools **which** would benefit considerably from*